# Matching across two data frames with certain observations having multiple entries to match against

Tags: r, string, merge, dataframe

I working with two data frames corresponding to the sample below:

```
# Data sets
set.seed(1)
dta_a <- data.frame(some_value = runif(n = 10), 
                    identifier=c("A0001","A0002","A0003","A0004","A0005",
                                 "A0006","B0001","B0002","B0003","B0004"),
                    other_val = runif(n = 10))
dta_b <- data.frame(variable_abc = runif(n = 6), 
                    identifier=c("A0001","A0002","A0003,A0004,A0005,C0001",
                                 "B0001,B0002","B0003","B0004"),
                    variable_df = runif(n = 6))
```

I would like to merge those two data frames and obtain a data frame similar to the one presented below:

[image: Desired results: data frame]

The resulting data frame would have the following qualities:

1. For the observations where only *one identifier* is present the `merge` command performs with `all.y = TRUE` and `all.x = FALSE` assuming that `y` is `dta_b`.
2. For the observations where *multiple identifiers* are provided only the first **matched** value from the `dta_a` is taken with the remaining values ignored. If there is no match on the first identifier (`A0003`) I would like for the command to attempt to match the next one (`A0004`).

---

I made a reference to the `merge` command but, naturally, `dplyr` and other solutions are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can 'melt' the dta_b so to have one row per identifier with a preference order and then join all the identifiers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
melt_dta_b = lapply(1:nrow(dta_b), function(i){
 split_identifier = strsplit(as.character(dta_b$identifier[i]), split = ",", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
 data_frame(identifier = split_identifier, 
         original_identifier = dta_b$identifier[i], original_row = i, preference = 1:length(identifier), 
         variable_abc = dta_b$variable_abc[i], variable_df = dta_b$variable_df[i])
})
melt_dta_b = rbind_all(melt_dta_b)
```

At that point you can select only the one with the highest preference score:

```
joined_df = left_join(melt_dta_b, dta_a) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(some_value)) %>% 
  group_by(original_row) %>% 
  filter(preference == min(preference)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

UPDATE

in order to not explicitly call the variables by name you can use the following code that binds all the 'unused' columns of the orginal df:

```
melt_dta_b = lapply(1:nrow(dta_b), function(i){
  tmp = dta_b[i,]
  split_identifier = strsplit(as.character(tmp$identifier), split = ",", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  colnames(tmp)[2] = "original_identifier"
  data_frame(identifier = split_identifier, original_row = i, preference = 1:length(identifier)) %>% 
    cbind(tmp)
})
melt_dta_b = rbind_all(melt_dta_b)
```

Comment: would it be possible to change the code `variable_abc = dta_b$variable_abc[i], variable_df = dta_b$variable_df[i]` to a loop where I could jump through all variable available in the file. I was thinking of something on the lines:  `for (j in length(names(dta_awrd)) -1) { names(dta_awrd)[j] = dta_awrd[,names(dta_awrd)[j]] #Subset for i}`. In the actual data frames I have more column that I want to carry.

Answer (score 1):

Just one way of doing it, but not best way I guess. Just made a try.
Split the identifiers and merge according to the first one.

```
dta_a$identifier = as.vector(dta_a$identifier)
dta_a1 = data.frame(dta_a, identifier_split = do.call(rbind, strsplit(dta_a$identifier, split = ",", fixed = T)))
dta_b$identifier = as.vector(dta_b$identifier)
dta_b1 = data.frame(dta_b, identifier_split = do.call(rbind, strsplit(dta_b$identifier, split = ",", fixed = T)))

dta_join = merge(dta_a1, dta_b1, by =  "identifier_split.1", all.x = F, all.y = T)
```

In cases you don't have a match for the first one, you'll see NAs and you can subset them and merge with second ones ("identifier_split.2")